# Left and right nav not sticky

Tags: html, css

I have a layout where I have specified a left and right nav. The left and right nav should have `position:sticky`. But for some reason, it is not sticking.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fcc;
  z-index: 100;
}

main {
  padding-top: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

main::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 230px;
  background-color: #ccf;
  height: 400px;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 490px);
  height: 1500px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #cfc;
  height: 300px;
  width: 260px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Some header
</header>
<main>
  <nav class="left">
    Some links
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    Some content
  </div>
  <nav class="right">
    Some more lnks
  </nav>
</main>
```

If you like to play with it in CodePen, here is the [CodePen link](https://codepen.io/vijayst/pen/rJvepZ?editors=1100#0).

Comment: Today I learned that `position: sticky` is actually a "thing." Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fcc;
  z-index: 100;
}

main {
  padding-top: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

main::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}


.left {
  float: left;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 230px;
  background-color: #ccf;
  height: 400px;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 490px);
  height: 1500px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #cfc;
  height: 300px;
  width: 260px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Some header
</header>
<main>
  <nav class="left">
    Some links
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    Some content
  </div>
  <nav class="right">
    Some more lnks
  </nav>
</main>
```

You Need to add `display` property to pseudo after element.

```
main::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

add this css and give a try.